# How to bring a Message box Window

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-3.0, c#-to-vb.net

In VB one can easily do this to bring up a Message box:

`MsgBox("Hello")`

How to achieve the same in `C#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: You can use MessageBox.Show("Hello");

Comment: what do you mean "dynamically allocate a string"? There is no such concept in c#. Strings are immutable (you can't change them once you create them), and you are allowed to create a string of any length.

Comment: No. Why do you need to do such a thing? If you want to have a string that you want to append to over time, you can use the StringBuilder class which is made for that purpose..

Comment: @user667389: `string[2000]` specifies an array of 2,000 strings. Did you mean that or did you mean `char[2000]`, which would be an array of characters? Either way, both are different from a simple string. Perhaps you should describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you have a C# string question please ask separately.